# Embedded Lockdown Manager shows no items under device

Tags: windows-embedded-8

After installing Windows 8.1 Embedded Industry Pro, and ELM, no lockdown options are listed under the local device (`IDEAL-TEST`):

[image]

How can I access the lockdown options?

Comment: To the downvoter, consider retracting your downvote. The reason that this question lacks intricate detail is because I also posted the answer. This is something I just expected to work after installing ELM. The FAQ on Microsoft's site just describes checking your password isn't blank, and that there's a standard user account added; which sends you off on a wild goosechase. This is my first install of 8.1 - I stuck with Windows 7 when 8 came out; and I hadn't thought to look in *Turn Windows features on or off*.

Answer (score 2):

First press Start, then type *features*, and select *Turn Windows features on or off*.

From there, check the *Embedded Features* box, and make sure to expand it and check each child item (this won't happen automatically by checking *Embedded Features*):

[image]

After a reboot, ELM will show the lockdown options:

[image]